# IT Project Management tool aimed at developers, but still generic enough for general purpose use?

Tags: tfs, project-management, trac

I am a lead software developer, and I have just been tasked with revamping our software development process. Part of this will be to implement a system with the following:

Source Control
Build automation
Project management/ reporting
Unit Testing
Bug tracking
Continuous integration

Now on the face of it, MS Team Foundation Server seems like the most obvious choice, especially as we are generally a MS software team, using Visual Studio and VSS.

*However* the snag is that solution would ideally be used by the whole IT department for Project Management/ reporting and Issue management, and as far as I know TFS is really aimed at software development.

So my question(s) is:
Does such a set up exist?
Is TFS flexible enough to facilitate more generic IT project ?
Would it be better to implement Trac, SVN etc (because at Trac may well suit the IT department generally), and we could bolt on svn, Nunit, and other tools to meet the requirements list?

Thanks for reading - any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be better asked on the [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have moved to [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com) a long time ago as we have found the exact same issue with TFS. It is good for our dev team but as soon as you want to open it up to other people / departments it doesn't work well. Gemini allowed us to change the labels so everyone in the business understands what they see.

We have integrated it with SVN, unit testing and our custom build CRM system.

Comment: Thanks I'll give Gemini a shot!